# Django Deployment in AWS Lightsail- static file not loading

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-lightsail

I am having a problem with deployment of Django application using AWS Lightsail referring to [this video](https://youtu.be/ldUo5EcRyGw).

The static file is not being loaded.

The static url and directory in my settings.py are as mentioned below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

The static folder is in the base directory named as /static/.

and the httpd-app.conf file in the conf folder has:

```
Alias /static/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/static"
<Directory opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/static>
Require all granted</Directory>

Alias /media/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/media"
<Directory opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` command and the static files are loaded in static directory but the site does not load it.

Comment: Have you created new folders inside /opt/bitnami? Asking this because atm there's no apps folder in there. Can you go to your Django project root folder, run `pwd` and share here the full path you get? Also, what is your project name?